# Git hook on Ubuntu broken

Tags: bash, git, shell, scripting, githooks

I recently got a git hook from someone that aims to add the issue number, which is in a specific location of the branch name, to the beginning of all commits. The goal is to take the `#number` from `feature/#number-issue`. Here is some info:

```
➜  .githooks pwd
/home/luctia/.githooks
➜  .githooks git config --global --list
user.name=luctia
user.email=myemail
core.hookspath=/home/luctia/.githooks
➜  .githooks cat commit-msg 
#!/bin/sh

WI=$(git status --branch | grep -iPo "(feature|bug)\/#\d+" | head -1)
WI=$(echo "($WI)" | grep -Po "\d+")

if [[ ! -z "$WI" ]]; then
    WI="#$WI"
    CM=$(cat "$1")
    if [[ ! $CM == *"$WI "* ]]; then
        echo "$WI $CM" > "$1"
    fi
fi
```

This doesn't seem to work, though. The script is executable for every user, so that's not the issue. I have tried switching from `sh` to `bash`, and with that edit I've executed the script on a file in a repo, which added the number to the beginning of the file, so I know it works. I'm not sure if git hooks can execute bash files, but it doesn't make a difference whether I use `sh` or `bash`, though I would like to know if it can run bash scripts.

I'm using Webstorm for my IDE right now, and it doesn't work in there, and it also doesn't work on CLI git. I have no idea how to proceed.

Edit: I am pretty sure the script is not executed. When I add `data > /tmp/hook` to the script, no file appears. I do have to change from `sh` to `bash` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to make this work on a pre-existing project, with an existing `.git` directory. I thought changing the config with the `--global` flag would just work, but apparently the config inside the `.git` directory of the project did not change, and the old `hookspath` was still there. When I changed it, the script started working.